# Can you know use Individuals in Journey Builder with API Update

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, individual

A general question, the latest release of SFMC has updated the API that journey builder uses with Salesforce.  As such, you should now in theory be able to inject an "Individual" into a Journey just as you would a Lead/Contact from Salesforce (or infact, any other object).  Has anyone managed this yet?  I wanted to find out if it is an additional feature we need, or if I have read the latest release correctly (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2019_journey_builder_mc_connect_API_version.htm&type=5).  We started to use Individual recently and really hope this will help us.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5) speaks to a change in who you can inject into a journey with a Salesforce Entry event:

> When configuring the event, select who enters a journey, such as leads, contacts, person accounts, or users.